# Using .append() in a loop to add text from an object after a <select> based on the selected option

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I want to insert a peace of text under a dropdown menu after an option has been selected based on what option was selected. I've written code that will do exactly what I want it to. But it seems like there should be a faster and more elegant way to handle what I'm trying to do. I'm thinking loop but loops confuse me a bit and I'm not sure what I've done wrong with the function I wrote to try do this.

Here is my original working code:

```
$('#Total_Package_Pool_Size').change(function() {               
    $('#PS_Dyn_warn').empty();
    $('#PS_Dyn_warn').append("This is the exact size of the pool, this is not an up to size.")

    var PS_Warning_Obj = {
        one : " A pool 14 x 28 is track space 14 and track length 29",
        two : " A pool 16 x 32 is track space 16 and track length 33",
        three: " A pool 18 x 34 is track space 18 and track length 35",
        four : " A pool 20 x 40 is track space 20 and track lenght 41"
    };

    var PS_Warning = document.getElementById('PS_Dyn_warn');
    var sizeDD = document.getElementById('Total_Package_Pool_Size');
    var sizeOpt = sizeDD.options[sizeDD.selectedIndex].text;
    switch (sizeOpt) {
        case "14 x 28":
            $('#PS_Dyn_warn').show();
            $("#PS_Dyn_warn").append(PS_Warning_Obj.one);
         break;
        case "16 x 32":
            $('#PS_Dyn_warn').show();
            $("#PS_Dyn_warn").append(PS_Warning_Obj.two);
         break;
        case "18 x 36":
            $('#PS_Dyn_warn').show();
            $("#PS_Dyn_warn").append(PS_Warning_Obj.three);
         break;
        case "20 x 40":
            $('#PS_Dyn_warn').show();
            $("#PS_Dyn_warn").append(PS_Warning_Obj.four);
         break;
    }   
});
```

And here is the loop I tried to write:

```
    var PS_Warning_Obj = {};
    PS_Warning_Obj['14x28'] = [" A pool 14 x 28 is track space 14 and track length 29"];
    PS_Warning_Obj['16x32'] = [" A pool 16 x 32 is track space 16 and track length 33"];
    PS_Warning_Obj['18x36'] = [" A pool 18 x 34 is track space 18 and track length 35"];
    PS_Warning_Obj['20x40'] = [" A pool 20 x 40 is track space 20 and track lenght 41"];
function Dynamic_PS_Warning() {
        $('#PS_Dyn_warn').empty();
        $('#PS_Dyn_warn').append("This is the exact size of the pool, this is not an up to size.")
        var sizeDD = document.getElementById('Total_Package_Pool_Size');
        var sizeOpt = sizeDD.options[sizeDD.selectedIndex].text;
        var PS_Warning = document.getElementById('PS_Dyn_warn');

        var psArray = PS_Warning_Obj[sizeOpt];
        if (psArray) {
            for (var i = 0; i < psArray.length; i++) {
                for (x in PS_Warning_Obj) {
                    if (psArray === sizeOpt) {
                        PS_Warning.append(PS_Warning_Obj[x];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is more dynamic, just inserting the numbers in the strings

```
$('#Total_Package_Pool_Size').change(function () {
    var sizeOpt = $('#Total_Package_Pool_Size option:selected').text(),
        arr     = sizeOpt.split('x').map(function(x) {
            return +$.trim(x);
        }),
        text1   = "This is the exact size of the pool, this is not an up to size.",
        text2   =  "A pool " + sizeOpt + " is track space " + arr[0] + " and track length " + (arr[1] + 1)

    $('#PS_Dyn_warn').text(text1 + text2).show();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rt6uu7nj/)

Comment: Awesome, that is a much more elegant way to do it! One question. What does the +$ operator mean in your return? is that just to tell the return to use the jquery .trim command on x before its returned?

Comment: The plus sign coerces the string to a number, that's all, if you type `+"3"` you end up with the integer `3`, could have used `parseInt` as well. It needs to be a number to add to it, if we do `"3" + 1` we end up with `"31"` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this much more flexible by removing the hard coding of the messages and making it dynamic. Also you were mixing jQuery with vanilla JavaScript. You weren't taking full advantage of jQuery.

```
$('#Total_Package_Pool_Size').change(function() {
    var dimensions = $(this).val().split('x');
    var space = parseInt(dimensions[0]);
    var length = parseInt(dimensions[1]);

    var message = 'This is the exact size of the pool, this is not an up to size.';
    message += ' A pool ' + space + ' x ' + length + ' is track space ' + space + ' and track length ' + (length + 1);

    $('#PS_Dyn_warn')
        .show()
        .text(message);
});
```

This uses the value of the select option rather than the text, which is much better. Your HTML should be something like the following:

```
<select id="Total_Package_Pool_Size">
    <option value="14x28">14 x 28</option>
    <option value="16x32">16 x 32</option>
    <option value="18x36">18 x 36</option>
    <option value="20x40">20 x 40</option>
</select>
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5e07g1oy/)